# How to prevent the view from passing under the navigation expo tabBar

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I've created a component bringing together two other components, the first being a calendar and the second being a list of another component I haven't yet created:

In this code, `SafeView` is a custom component ([see the code here](https://github.com/bouteillerAlan/summit-app/blob/feat/workout/components/safeView.tsx)). But, for Android, this is just a view with a padding top.

```js
const Dashboard = (): ReactElement => {
  // first load is today
  const [pressedDate, setPressedDate] = useState<dayData>({ date: DateTime.now(), isToday: true, isPressed: false });

  return (
    <SafeView>
      <RowCalendar readUserPressedDate={(pressedDate: dayData): void => { setPressedDate(pressedDate); }}/>
      <WorkoutList dayData={pressedDate}/>
    </SafeView>
  );
};
```

This code is called in a `_layout` file to be handled by [expo-router](https://expo.github.io/router/docs/).

```js
const Layout = (): ReactElement => {
  const iconSize = 20;

  return (
    <Tabs screenOptions={{
      headerShown: true,
      tabBarShowLabel: true,
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000'
    }}>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name='dashboard'
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: (stg: tabBarIconProps) => <FontAwesome5 name='dumbbell' color={stg.color} size={iconSize}/>
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name='analytics'
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: (stg: tabBarIconProps) => <FontAwesome5 name='chart-line' color={stg.color} size={iconSize}/>
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name='settings'
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: (stg: tabBarIconProps) => <FontAwesome5 name='cog' color={stg.color} size={iconSize}/>
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

My problem is the WorkoutList ([code here](https://github.com/bouteillerAlan/summit-app/blob/feat/workout/components/workoutList.tsx)) component pass below the bottom bar created by expo-router with `Tabs` :
[image]

The `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` on the `ScrollView` do nothing. Same with `flex: 1`.

If I put the following option on my `Tabs` is height remain the same :

```js
tabBarStyle: { height: 50 }
```

But I need to set the height of the `paddingBottom` component to 125 if I want the last item of the list to be showed.

Why 125 and not 50 ?

What is the "normal" way to handle that ? Is there a way to retrieve the height of this bottom bar ?

[Full code here.](https://github.com/bouteillerAlan/summit-app/tree/feat/workout)

Comment: did you find anything out on this?

Comment: @PhilLucks nope